# Why does mutating one property (Object) also change in a different and separately declared property?

Tags: javascript, angular, mutation

I have 2 properties declared like so:

```
ngOnInit() {
this.defaultRequirements = myData.property1.countryDocument; //should never change
this.filteredRequirements = myData.property1.countryDocument; 
}
```

When I run this onFilter function, the defaultRequirements property also gets mutated.

```
onFilter(selectedSections) {
    let index = -1;

    this.defaultRequirements.forEach(country => {
      index++;
      const filteredSectionsList = [];

      country.section.forEach(section => {
        selectedSections.value.forEach(selectedSelection => {
          const selection = selectedSelection.split(/\s*[-]\s*/);  

          if (country.countryCode === selection[0]) {
            console.log('matched');
            filteredSectionsList.push(section);
          }
        });

        const countryObj = Object.assign({}, country, {
          section: [...filteredSectionsList]
        })

// Here is the issue, when filtering, this.defaultRequirements also gets changed!
        this.filteredRequirements[index] = countryObj;


      })
    })
```

}

**The Problem**

I don't understand how mutating this.filteredRequirements is ALSO mutating this.defaultRequirements (they both equal the same thing)! How can I avoid this behaviour and have defaultRequirements be unaffected by changes done on filteredRequirements?

Comment: They both point by reference to the same object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so your declared object `myData.property1.countryDocument` is a non-primitive/reference value.  So that means that both `this.defaultRequirements` and `this.filteredRequirements` are pointing to literally the same piece of data.

If you were to do this with a primitive value (eg: a `string`), you would get a copy; so `this.defaultRequirements` and `this.filteredRequirements` would be completely separate and could be manipulated with no effect on each other.

To duplicate/copy an object in the way that you intended is totally possible and there's been a lot of discussion about it already which I won't duplicate; I'd suggest [you take a look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript/5344074#5344074) which covers it nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.defaultRequirements = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myData.property1.countryDocument));   
    this.filteredRequirements = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myData.property1.countryDocument));
}
```

or

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.defaultRequirements = {...myData.property1.countryDocument}
    this.filteredRequirements = {...myData.property1.countryDocument}
}
```

Comment: The first method is supported in all browsers, but second method is not supported in IE browser. @Kode_12